# django: access elements from another template

Tags: javascript, python, django, web-applications, django-templates

```
project/
|----app1/
     |----templates/
                   app1/                       
                   |----home.html
                   |----exchange.html
```

I need to perform calculations on the home.html using javascript, but some data is stored in the table inside exchange.html, and I don't want to put them together under one page. how would I go about that. I am very new to python and django.

```
{% include "exchange.html" %}
```

I tried this on home.html but it loads all the content which i don't need. can anybody help please.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
        <caption>Exchange rate</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>GBP</th>
                <th>EUR</th>
                <th>USD</th>
                <th>CAD</th>
                <th>AUD</th>
            </tr>       
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>GBP</td>
                <td><input type="number" value="1" readonly></td>
                <td><input class="rate" type="number"></td>
                <td><input class="rate" type="number"></td>
                <td><input class="rate" type="number"></td>
                <td><input class="rate" type="number"></td>
            </tr>                   
            <tr>
                <td>EUR</td>
                <td><input class="rate" type="number"></td>
                <td><input type="number" value="1" readonly></td>
                <td><input class="rate" type="number"></td>
                <td><input class="rate" type="number"></td>
                <td><input class="rate" type="number"></td>
            </tr>
                <td>USD</td>
                <td><input class="rate" type="number"></td>
                <td><input class="rate" type="number"></td>
                <td><input type="number" value="1" readonly></td>
                <td><input class="rate" type="number"></td>
                <td><input class="rate" type="number"></td>
            <tr>
                <td>CAD</td>
                <td><input class="rate" type="number"></td>
                <td><input class="rate" type="number"></td>
                <td><input class="rate" type="number"></td>
                <td><input type="number" value="1" readonly></td>
                <td><input class="rate" type="number"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>AUD</td>
                <td><input class="rate" type="number"></td>
                <td><input class="rate" type="number"></td>
                <td><input class="rate" type="number"></td>
                <td><input class="rate" type="number"></td>
                <td><input type="number" value="1" readonly></td>
            </tr>           
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I have this table in exchage.html where users can input the exchange rate, and I need to to do some calculation on home.html using the relevant rate.

Comment: Create a separate html which consists of the data which u require and use include tag to add that into home .html

Comment: provide full path of your required `.html` file in `include`

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a small piece of html that contains only the information that you need, and put it in another file, **calculations.html** for example. You don't put *all* of the code from exchange.html in there, only the duplicated part.

Then use the include tag to add that HTML from both the exchange.html and home.html.

```
{% include calculations.html %}
```

Comment: but i don't want to show the whole table in home.html, i want just some specific values which i can reference using javascript and do calculations. i am now looking at ajax, do that work ??

Comment: Well don't add the whole table, only add the actual parts you need. Javascript is one way of doing that  (Ajax would imply a server call, not sure if that is needed). But you would need to show more details to get an understanding of what you are trying to achieve.